# Convert rows into columns using (Notepad++)

Tags: notepad++

I am trying to convert domain name extensions rows to columns

```
|.ac
|.ad
|.af
|.ag
|.ai
```

TO

```
|.ac|.ad|.af|.ag|.ai
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace linebreak by nothing:

- Find what: `\R`
- Replace with: `NOTHING`